# Create Hyperlink using textbox on UserForm and Path specified

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, userform

I have a table for users to import new info/data onto, using a UserForm.

I would like the User to type the document name because the File is not labeled correctly (which I don't care much about) I would like the textbox to be the label for the hyperlink and the Path be selected by the user after they've moved the file into it's appropriate folder.

```
Private Sub cmd_ADD_Click()
    'Copy input values to table2.
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add
Dim Label17 As String
Dim txtDrawing As String

With newrow
```

this line worked originally

```
    .Range(13) = txtDrawings.Value
```

now I need that value, when added to be a hyperlink. I tried this...

```
    .Range(13).Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=.Range(13), _
      Address:=Label17, _
      ScreenTip:="DRAWING", _
      TextToDisplay:=txtDrawings.Value)
```

and this...

```
    .Range(13) = .Hyperlinks.Add(Label17, Me.txtDrawings.Value)

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

With newrow
    .Range(13).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(13), _
                              Address:=Label17.Caption, _
                              ScreenTip:="DRAWING", _
                              TextToDisplay:=txtDrawings.Value
End With
```

1. Remove the brackets before `Anchor:` in your code. Also remove any `On Error Resume Next`. Now try the above
2. Delete the lines `Dim Label17 As String` and `Dim txtDrawing As String`. Those are controls.

Comment: thanks for your input. But it appears a hyperlink is created but it doesn't work with the path specified by Lable17. It seams to me as if it hyperlinked the current document for some reason.  I removed ScreenTip line and when i hover over the hyperlink it states the path to the current document.

Comment: What is the value of label17? Also is it a form control or an ActiveX Control (the label)

Comment: Lable17 is populated after the user selects the file with msoFileDialogFilePicker. when i create the hyperlink the old fashion way it works fine. Oh, and the Label is on a UserForm. I'm not sure what type of Control that may be.

Comment: Your label needs to have an exact path.. for example "C:\SampleFolder\Book1.xlsx"` so that `Address:=Label17` becomes `Address:=C:\SampleFolder\Book1.xlsx`

Comment: I think I know what problem you are facing... Where is the label? in a userform or a worksheet?

Comment: Label17 is on the userform. Could it be that the Path (which is the text string of Label17 doesn't have parentheses?

Comment: Then why `Dim Label17 As String`? :) Delete that.